# AngularJS controller, required by directive, can't be found

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an error for each "message"

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'accordion', required by directive 'accordionGroup', can't be found!
```

with my code in html

```
<h2 data-ng-if="!!messageData.messages.length">Messages</h2>

<accordion close-others="true">
    <accordion-group data-ng-repeat="m in messageData.messages">
        <accordion-heading>
            <span>{{ m.head }}</span>
            <span class="pull-right">{{ m.created | date:'d-MMM-yyyy HH:mm' }}</span>
        </accordion-heading>
        <p>{{ m.body }}</p>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

but messages are views with no problems

**UPD 1:**
i tried to debug angular.js and function getControllers return different values for "empty accordion-group" and "accordion-group with ng-repeat", difference is in line

```
value = value || $element[retrievalMethod]('$' + require + 'Controller');
```

value is undefined for "ng-repeat acordion-group" and not null for "empty accordion group"

**UPD COMPLETE**
I'm update my VS2013 to RC2 and problems solved.

Comment: make a plunkr or a fiddle or provide more code so we can help you.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/tZ39SBMDpJ3dEzdjmCjN?p=info

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for having the time to provide a plunkr. I modified it a bit by excluding the non-needed libs and also using `data-ng-xx` notation. I also used the appropriate way of injecting scope:

```
['$scope', function($scope){
....
}]
```

I also put `ng-app` on body and after head cause of a possible script loading order issue. Here is the Plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Rftdxz4erSeHT14cp2ID?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i still have a problem. Try to use this code on your system. I can't guarantee that plunker show valid information about errors, because it processed at plunker's server.

Comment: I have used the same code on a simple web page. It doesn't give me any errors. What kind of browser are you running?

Comment: I am doing that exactly in Chrome and Firefox in Ubuntu and I don't get absolutely no error.

Comment: Ohhh... i'm update my visual studio to RC 2 and problems solved.